# Do not allow cross-domain redirection intentionally – Struts2 web application url redirection issue

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, struts2, tomcat7

I have developed a web application using JSP + Struts2 + Hibernate with MYSQL as the back-end. While performing security testing of my application URL redirects to cross – domain websites. For an example, I am running my application in Google chrome browser

localhost:8080/test/welcome.action

It works fine. While entering redirect:http://google.com application allowing to redirect google home page instead of application home page or custom page.

localhost:8080/test/welcome.action?redirect:http://google.com

The above action should not be allowed in security testing, because hackers can get the data(session information) from my application to some other application.

I need solution to stop above redirect to some other URL. Please advise or suggest me how can I prevent to show my application home page instead of cross-domain page.

Comment: Are you saying that adding `?redirect:http://google.com` to any action url is redirecting to google? Which S2 version are you using? Show your action configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There is nothing change or modification in configuration file. If i run my application in browser URL will be displayed like localhost:8080/appname/index.action here  i entered manually localhost:8080/appname/index.action?redirect:http://google.com and hit go button it was going to google.com. It should not be redirect. since application should not allow cross-domain redirect. Hope this input helps you to identify error.

Comment: I've added `?redirect:http://google.com` to my app index action and no things happens!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to restrict third party URL. The solution to update latest versions of Struts 2 jar files. It will be automatically works correctly. To include Struts 2 and dependency jar file as

commons-fileupload-1.3.2

commons-io-2.4

commons-io-2.4

commons-lang-2.4

commons-lang3-3.4

commons-logging-1.1.3

freemarker-2.3.23

javassist-3.20.0-GA

ognl-3.1.12

struts2-core-2.5.10.1

Refer below link: 
https://struts.apache.org/docs/s2-016.html

Comment: That is why I asked you which version of S2 you're using.